# How to detect load is connected to a MOSFET?

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, gpio, load

How can I detect a load is connected to a MOSFET and report that back to the MCU?
So the MOSFET can be ON or OFF, but I need to know in both situations if there's something connected or not.

NOTE: if it involves an additional GPIO, then id like to add an indicator LED instead.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDX6yc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Please draw a schematic of how everything is connected. Can you live with say 1 uA leaking into your load?

Comment: Perhaps using a smart switch, instead? Also, the load can be few micro amperes or several tens of amperes, so how would a device report its state?

Comment: When the MOSFET is *on*, measure current as the voltage across a small sense resistor between the MOSFET and the supply rail it switches.  When it is *OFF* place a high value resistor across the FET to leak a little bit of current into a load, and see if there's full voltage across the empty terminals, or a reduced one across a load which *is* present.  **For more specifics you will have to edit your question to provide more details**

Comment: @MarkoBuršič can you give an example of a smart switch?

Comment: You can download some app notes on Infineon, NXP, ...any other manufacturer that produces MOSFET smart switches for automotive, industry, ...etc